# How can I force Glade to be in English?

Tags: application-development, quickly, locale, glade

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Polish localization. If I start: "quickly design", Glade shows up with Polish interface. I don't like that, I'd like Glade to be in English. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Glade in English by giving

```
env LANG="en_US.UTF-8" quickly design
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C quickly design
```

or

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; quickly design
```

commands in terminal. If you want to set permanently Glade's language to English, you can edit the launcher of Glade with the help of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand). You have to change 'Exec' line like this:

```
Exec=env LC_ALL=C quickly design
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Although the first command gives me an error message, the rest are fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually simple. Instead of

`quickly design`

run:

`LANG=en quickly design`.

This trick works for almost every application, since they all determine your language settings on the basis of LANG (sometimes LANGUAGE or LC_MESSAGES are also significant).

Comment: I believe for the `LANG` environment variable you'll have to specify a fully qualified locale name (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`). If you want to simply specify `en`, you should be using the `LANGUAGE` variable